# How to select sales from 12PM today to next day 5AM in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a requirement to select the daily sales from Present Day 12PM to Next Day 5AM is there any way to do this.

Example: `2018-11-08 12:00` To `2018-11-09 05:00` (when initiated on 2018-11-08)

I am able to retrieve daily sales before `23:59` but unable to do get the next day's sales up to 05:00.

I have `Orders` table that have `Order_date` datatype is `TEXT` and datetime format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm`

Comment: @vizsatiz sqlite doesn't have a "datetime" type. If OP is storing timestamps as strings, `TEXT` is the appropriate type. (Personally, I'd use the unix time in an `INTEGER` affinity column instead)

Comment: Show what you've tried already in your query.

Comment: @vizsatiz sqlite doesn't support datetime and i have seen the best datatype is `TEXT` for storing datetime in sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following could be used :-

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
  WHERE order_date 
    BETWEEN (strftime('%Y-%m-%d','now')||' 12:00') 
    AND (strftime('%Y-%m-%d','now','+1 days')||' 05:00')
;
```

### Working Example

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders (order_date TEXT);
INSERT INTO orders (order_date) VALUES
        (strftime('%Y-%m-%d','now','-1 days')||' 11:59'), -- before
        (strftime('%Y-%m-%d','now')||' 00:00'), -- before
        (strftime('%Y-%m-%d','now')||' 11:59'), -- before (just)
        (strftime('%Y-%m-%d','now')||' 12:00'), --*** included
        (strftime('%Y-%m-%d','now')||' 23:59'), --*** included
        (strftime('%Y-%m-%d','now','+1 days')||' 05:00'), --**** included
        (strftime('%Y-%m-%d','now','+1 days')||' 05:01') -- after (just)
    ;

SELECT * FROM orders 
 WHERE order_date 
   BETWEEN (strftime('%Y-%m-%d','now')||' 12:00') 
   AND (strftime('%Y-%m-%d','now','+1 days')||' 05:00')
;
```

- Those marked with *** are rows (3 of them) that should be selected.
  [image]

Comment: I want to start current day from noon 12PM so i will change `00:00` to `12:00` right?

Comment: i don't have AM or PM my `Order_Date` format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm` example `2018-11-08 14:00`

Comment: @Beeman yep sorry missed 12PM. However the AM/PM makes things a little more difficult (need to add 12 hours for PM). Working on that now.

Comment: @Beeman in the example you included. However, makes life easier to not have so won't change (might edit your post to remove AM PM so as not to confuse.)